# SoundManager2 not working with TurboLinks

Tags: soundmanager2, turbolinks

Page changes with TurboLinks get rid of the flash video inserted by SoundManager2, breaking it . When I play something it throws (Chromium 25):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method '_createSound'
```

I tried calling reboot:

```
soundManager.reboot() if soundManager.ok()
```

But then it throws `has no method '_destroySound'`.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fixed it:

```
recreateSoundManager = ->
  sm2 = window.soundManager
  if sm2?.ok()
    sm2 = window.soundManager = new SoundManager() 
  sm2
```

Call this on turbolinks page load before the setup of soundmanager2. Then you can either use the return value or access normally from `window.soundManager`.

Example with jquery.turbolinks:

```
jQuery ->
  soundManager = recreateSoundManager()
  soundManager.setup url: '/'
```